# IE6/7 right floating bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
#container {
background-color: #CCC;
height:100px;
}
.clear-fix
{
    overflow: hidden;
    _height:1%;
}
#navigation {
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
background-color:Aqua;
}
#content {
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
background-color:Orange;
}        
#content div{display:inline; float:right;}
#content a {float:right; display:inline;margin-right:5px;}


<body style="direction:rtl">
<div id="container" class="clear-fix">
<div id="navigation"><a href="#">hi there ddd ddd</a></div>
<div id="content">
    <div>somthing else</div>
    <a target="_blank" href="#" ><img src="anything.jpg" style="width:32px; height:32px"/></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="#" ><img src="anything.jpg" style="width:32px; height:32px" /></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

IE6/7 not show correctly (left-side). i don't want set width for #content do you know any fixer for IE?
if i float inner element of content to left, it is correct (after re arrange of element),
but i want float element to right.

please tell me your solution.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure, but from the top of my head... try this
You can add these and see

```
#container{
    width:[your width];
}
#content{
    display: inline-block;
}
```